# How to use type reference nullable or how to enable it on preview in .NET Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nullable, preview

My problem is that i keep having the error **CS8652**

"C# The feature is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the language version."

By using "?" after the type to authorize the property to be null during a deserialization (i use JsonConvert if it helps, maybe there is a parameter that authorize some property to be null, but i don't really think so)

```
class Data
{
    String? PropertyCanBeNull { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried almost all i've found to resolve this error including the following  : 
    - Install Visual Studio 2019 Preview
    - Install .NET SDK for preview (and checking in CMD that it worked)
    - Modified my project property so that it use the .NET Core 3.0+ version

I also tried to change the language version for my project, but it seems it's useless in my case.

"When your project targets a preview framework that has a corresponding preview language version, **the language version used is the preview language version**."

Source : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

**Answered by Dirk in comments** :

I also remember using the "?" after the type some time ago, but i'm not really sure, did they do any change to it so that it is supported only in "preview" or something ?

> Nullable value types (like int?) have been in C# for a very long time. Nullable reference types (like string?) however were introduced with C# 8.

Comment: Just to reassure: Did you set C# 8.0 in your project properties? Are you using Visual Studio 2019 Preview? And is VS up to date?

Comment: Nullable value types (like `int?`) have been in C# for a very long time. Nullable reference types (like `string?`) however were introduced with C# 8. You can change the language version in the project settings, the default might not be the highest.

Comment: That's the reason of my link, it seems that in preview version, the "default" (by default i mean that it won't change unless specified) is the langage for preview version in my case (C# 8.0+ if i remember well) , so it should be alright. And yes, my Visual Studio is up to date. Thanks for the precision Dirk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string is **Always** nullable in C#.

And while C# 8 will [introduce the nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#nullable-reference-types) like `public string?` this is also a problem NewtonSoft's JSON Converter has [had solved](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm) for some time:

```
string ignored = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movie,
    Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

---

#### Edit

I made it back to the machine with Visual Studio, fully updated to Visual Studio 2019 (16.2):

If you edit the project solution

1. Open the solution folder
2. Right-click the solution and edit

and add the following two settings to the PropertyGroup the warning will go away:

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, the part with a string always being nullable saved me, indeed, what i wanted wasn't nullable reference, but nullable value, and in fact, by writing ``` string? someString ``` it tells me about nullable reference, whereas ``` int? someInteger ``` refer to nullable value that don't require preview version. This confused me a lot, and now all is working. i don't know if i really should select your answer as the right one though, since my question was "How to use type reference nullable or how to enable it", it still doesn't work, even if i don't need it in my case.

Comment: I'll select this one as answer then, because it solved my problem, but if someone pass by and got the solution to the original question about enabling type reference nullable on visual studio preview, it would be great to post it here

Comment: @Luxior a) I'm deleting my previous comments to clean up this section, I added what should also fix the other half of the question